# scanning a line has strings and integer C

Tags: string, while-loop, scanf

### I have a project and im facing a problem in this code

```
void Show() {
system("cls");
FILE *AddedSc;
int sc1i,sc2i;
int sc1ii,sc2ii;
char TNi[100],TN2i[100];
char TNii[100],TN2ii[100];
AddedSc = fopen("addedscores.txt", "r");
printf("                     - Choose teams from this list: \n\n");
printf("                         1. Brazil\n                         2. Germany\n                         3. Italy\n                         4. KSA\n                         5. Portogual\n                         6. Australia\n                         7. USA\n                         8. Spin\n                         9. England\n                         10. Korea\n\n\n");

printf("         * Enter the two teams that you want to show their results:  ");
printf("\n\n\nTeam A: ");
scanf("%s", TNi);
printf("Team B: ");
scanf("%s", TN2i);

while (fscanf(AddedSc,"%[^\n] %d %d %[^\n]", TNii, sc1ii, sc2ii,TN2ii) !=EOF) {

    if (strcmp(TNi, TNii) == 0 && strcmp(TN2i, TN2ii) == 0)  
    printf("\n\n%s %d - %d %s", TNi, sc1ii, sc2ii, TN2i);
    else if(strcmp(TN2i, TNii) == 0 && strcmp(TNi, TN2ii) == 0)
    printf("\n\n%s %d - %d %s", TN2i, sc2ii, sc1ii, TNi);
    else printf("Not found!"); 

} 



fclose(AddedSc);
```

---

there is a file contains data like this

usa 2 0 italy

I want the user to enter the name of two teams and let the program to search in the file and compare what the user entered and print the result of the match on the screen ..

please help me in this....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first format, `%[^\n]`, which will eat up all the lines in the input. You can change it just `%s` as follows:

```
while (fscanf(AddedSc,"%s %d %d %s", TNii, sc1ii, sc2ii,TN2ii) != EOF)
```

And it will be safer to compare the result as:

```
while (fscanf(AddedSc,"%s %d %d %s", TNii, sc1ii, sc2ii,TN2ii) == 4)
```